# how to get raw html text of a given url using python

Tags: python, html

I'm using html2text in python to get raw text (tags included) of a HTML page by taking any URL but I'm getting an error.

My code -

```
import html2text
import urllib2

proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://<proxy>:<pass>@<ip>:<port>'})
auth = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy, auth, urllib2.HTTPHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ndtv.com/india-news/this-stunt-for-a-facebook-like-got-the-hyderabad-youth-arrested-740851").read()
print html2text.html2text(html)
```

The error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "t.py", line 8, in <module>
    html = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.ndtv.com/india-news/this-stunt-for-a-facebook-like-got-the-hyderabad-youth-arrested-740851").read()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 110] Connection timed out>
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with html2text; it's an error in the URL fetch. Can you load that URL through a browser? Can you just try it again? Network errors like this are often intermittent.

Comment: yep its working fine on browser ....any other suggestios..??

Comment: urllib2.urlopen already gives you the text; that error I don't know.

Comment: The error means that your script waited a long time but the server didn't say anything.

Comment: You need to improve your spelling and capitalization. I got banned for it once.

Comment: Seems connection issue. Please check your firewall, proxy and the main site to check which one is the culprit.

Comment: @RajibBiswas I guess so. My university internet was behind proxy.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't require SSL, this script in `Python 2.7.x`  should work:

```
import urllib
url = "http://stackoverflow.com"
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
print f.read()
```

and in `Python 3.x` use `urllib.request` instead of `urllib`

Because `urllib2` for Python 2, in Python 3 it was merged into `urllib`.

`http://` is required.

**EDIT:** In 2020, you should use the 3rd party module `requests`. `requests` can be installed with `pip`.

```
import requests
print(requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com").text)
```

Comment: sorry but it didnt help it gave the same error....do u have any other soltuion..??