# What is the best way to keep a file from my repo synced with an open source file on github?

Tags: git, github, synchronization

The thing is, let's say I have a private project on Github, and I want to keep the README.md from this project synced with an open source project such as Flutter repo, or React Repo, whatever. How could I do that with A GitHub bot or a .yaml which will run every time I commit to my repo?

I don't care if the solution will commit on my repo, or anything like that, I just want to find a way to keep this file synced.

Answer (score 0):

If running a python script as a cronjob is an acceptable solution you can use the GitHub API with the wrapper [PyGithub](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). Then you can decide how often to run this script and it does not need to be triggered by you doing an action at your repo. See a quick example below.

```py
from github import Github
g = Github("access_token")

#Get the repo you want to commit to
repo = g.get_repo("account_name/repo_name")

#Get the version of the file you want to commit to your repo. 
#Below assumes you have file locally relative to where you run this script
#See here from getting it from a URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28613470/6889416
file_content = open('local_path/README.md', 'rb').read()

#Get the commit sha from the current state of the file
sha = repo.get_contents("README.md").sha

#Update the README file
update = my_repo.update_file("README.md","Update README.md",file_content,sha,branch="main")
```

I took this on code I use to set up identical repos for each Git/GitHub training I use. If you want to see the full code, see [here](https://github.com/worldbank/dime-github-trainings/blob/master/GitHub-trainings/Intro-Git-GitHub-Contributor/jupyter-repo-setup/Setup%20TrainingRepo.ipynb).